# Using Parallel loop to give each datarow a score in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have a method which iterates through each DataRow of a DataTable then sets the final "Score" column to be a result.  I am trying to figure out how to do this quicker than simply evaluating in serial.  I am new to trying parallel loops and don't know if I am taking the wrong approach.

Simplified existing code:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in DateOptions.Rows) 
{ 
double score = evalRow(dr);
 dr["score"] = score; 
}
```

Using the following seems to result in error- as I am trying to modify the DataTable.

```
Parallel.ForEach(DateOptions.AsEnumerable(), dr =>
{
    double score = evalRow(dr);
     dr["score"] = score; 
});
```

Is there some way I am not thinking of to extract the result then apply the value to the appropriate column?

Comment: What specific error are you getting? And why do you want to do this in parallel?

Comment: It seems kind of sporadic.  Some times I am getting null reference exceptions from rows were not empty becoming empty.  Other times it is errors I don't really understand.  I want to run this in parallel to speed up processing time.  This is for a scheduling system to evaluate date options over thousands of operations.  My software completes in around 7 hours after streamlining many things but I need to get it under 6.  Im hoping using more processing power will help.

Comment: Could you include the `evalRow` method in the question?

Comment: The method is quite long with lots of sub methods. It does a lot of data lookups using the DataRowCollection.Find() method - which I am not sure is thread safe or not - examples are to get resource capacities, loads and days separation from other operations. It takes that information to calculate a final score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably depends largely on whether `evalRow` does anything that's not thread-safe. If the only problem is coming from modifying the DataTable, then you can likely fix it by applying Command-Query Separation: use parallel processing to figure out *what* to do, then drop back to serial processing to actually do it.

```
var rowsWithScores = DateOptions.AsEnumerable().AsParallel()
    .Select(dr => new {dr, score = evalRow(dr)})
    .ToList();
foreach(var rowWithScore in rowsWithScores)
{
    rowWithScore.dr["score"] = rowWithScore.score;
}
```

That said, in my experience problems like this are better solved with algorithmic fixes rather than just trying to throw parallel processing at it. If you're only dealing with *thousands* of items, and this is taking *hours* to complete, that tells me you're probably either using an algorithm with high complexity (which can probably be fixed using data structures), or doing a lot of I/O (which might lend itself to concurrent asynchronous operations). In other words, there's probably another approach that will get you orders of magnitude better performance.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out tomorrow.  Just some background: the problem is a little more complex and Im sure there is a better way but its functioning in production right now and I just need a little more performance.  There's hundred of processes each containing about 20 operations which can have up to about a hundred date options.  It runs through a lot of if/then scenarios in terms of optimizing a final score.  The loop itself probably gets called a few million times a night.

Comment: Have you run it through a profiler to see where it's spending the most time? Often you'll identify a single hot-spot in the calculation code (possibly something you had no idea took so much time) where a little optimization can yield huge dividends. Also, I seem to remember someone mentioning that they were able to see really big performance gains by taking their data out of a DataTable: apparently the performance of the DataTable structure itself is really abysmal. So maybe if your calculation could be done on regular objects, and then the DataTable just gets updated for display/output?

Comment: Is there a reason that you prefer to store the processed data in anonymous objects, instead of value-tuples?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: I just wasn't sure which version of C# you were using. Value Tuples are great, and your `foreach` loop could have a nicer syntax by using destructuring that way.

Comment: Havent gotten to try out he code from @StriplingWarrior yet.  But in all honesty software development is relatively new for me - Im an aerospace engineer who started making cutomizations to our ERP then progressed into more complex problems out of the necessity of limited personnel.  The issue is I have very little knowledge of types of collections and the intricacies associated with them.  Ive just used DataTables because Ive been able to accomplish what I need to with them and manipulating them is the majority of what I know.  I will look into converting the data to tuples and trying that.

Comment: Also @StriplingWarrior thanks for the profiler tip - will look into it.

Comment: @RobP.: Fun! Welcome to the world of software development. Good luck!